# Program Infinitely Looping

Tags: c++, function, loops, infinite-loop

This is a snippet of the code from my program.  The function getMenuChoice() runs successfully on Visual Studio when I enter integers but when I enter a character it goes into an infinite loop.  I was told that my program does not have to account for the user entering a character but yet when I submit it, the grading machine tells me it "exceeded the allowed length".  Besides the fact it does not account for characters, I am not sure what is wrong with the function.  If I was to account for characters though, how would I do that?

```
// Calls header and menu.
int main() {
    printHeading();
    getMenuChoice();
}

//Prints the header.
void printHeading() {
    cout << "*******************************" << endl
         << "      Birthday Calculator      " << endl
         << "*******************************" << endl << endl;
}

//Prints the closer.
void printCloser() {
    cout << endl;
    cout << "****************************************************" << endl
    << "      Thanks for using the Birthday Calculator      " << endl
    << "****************************************************" << endl
    << endl;
}
void printMenu() {
    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << "Menu Options" << endl
    << "------------" << endl;
    cout << "1) Determine day of birth" << endl;
    cout << "2) Print the next 10 leap years" << endl;
    cout << "3) Determine birthdays for the next 10 years" << endl;
    cout << "4) Finished" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Choice --> ";
}

//Gets user's menu choice.
int getMenuChoice() {
    int choice;
    printMenu();
    cin >> choice;

    //If user does not select 4, it selects their menu choice.
    while (choice != 4) {
        if (choice == 1) {
            determineDayOfBirth();
        }
        else if (choice == 2) {
            print10LeapYears();
        }
        else if (choice == 3) {
            print10Birthdays();
        }

        //User did not enter a valid choice and the following prints.
        else {
            cout << "Invalid menu choice" << endl;
        }

        //Allows the user to enter another choice
        //after they have executed one choice.
        printMenu();
        cin >> choice;
    }

    //Prints closer when user chooses 4.
    printCloser();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its been awhile since I played with C++ but here is a shot.

```
int choice;
printMenu();
cin >> choice;
ValidateOption(choice);

// Then if you want them to be able to pick again you can just do it over again
printMenu();
cin >> choice;
ValidateOption(choice);

function ValidateOption(int choice){
//If user does not select 4, it selects their menu choice.
while (choice != 4) {
    if (choice == 1) {
        determineDayOfBirth();
    }

    else if (choice == 2) {
        print10LeapYears();
    }

    else if (choice == 3) {
        print10Birthdays();
    }

    //Prints closer when user chooses 4.
    else if (choice == 4){
        printCloser();
        return 0;
    }
    //User did not enter a valid choice and the following prints.
    else {
        cout << "Invalid menu choice" << endl;
        // Make the user select again because the input was invalid    
        printMenu();
        cin >> choice;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to flush `cin` like this:

```
cin >> choice;
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(INT_MAX);
```

or as suggested by @user4581301

```
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Comment: Better if you put some bounds on that ignore.  `ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n')` is recommended. everything up to eol or end of stream. It is exceedingly unlikely, but INT_MAX might not be enough.

Comment: @user4581301 - I added your suggestion to the answer